# Getting Popup Screen after Clicking a Button

Tags: salesforce

Here I added Custom Functionality for a Button and When I Click a Button.

**Expected Result:** After Clicking a button it should navigate to child Component.

**Actual Result:** After Clicking a button it was Showing PopUp Screen and navigating to child Component.

Here I need to remove the Popup Screen. Can anyone help to come out from this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some code with us please? Generaly it should work like this:

```
view_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewCurent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank u for response. Here i need to Check in Browser level because Code has No Errors. Can u plz tell me Procedure to inspect Element